# MongoDB driver for node.js, transactions API, error "client.startSession() is not a function"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to use the MongoDB driver for node.js, for creating a transaction. Here is my code.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://someone:someone@somecluster.xxxyy.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

function dbConnect () {
    callback = callbackTrans;
    MongoClient.connect (uri, callback);
};

function callbackTrans (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var session = MongoClient.startSession();
    console.log ('so far so good');
};

dbConnect ();
```

It is incomplete code, of course. But I am getting the following error, when I run this program...

```
D:\NodeJS\node_modules\mongodb\lib\topologies\replset.js:339
          throw err;
          ^

TypeError: MongoClient.startSession is not a function
    at callbackTrans (D:\NodeJS\transaction.js:11:31)
    at D:\NodeJS\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:693:5
    at D:\NodeJS\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:227:7
    at connectCallback (D:\NodeJS\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:366:5)      
    at D:\NodeJS\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:602:5
    at ReplSet.connectHandler (D:\NodeJS\node_modules\mongodb\lib\topologies\replset.js:336:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ReplSet.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at D:\NodeJS\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\topologies\replset.js:796:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

What am I missing / doing incorrectly? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, `MongoClient.startSession();` is invalid because `startSession()` is not a static method on `MongoClient` but an instance method which should be called on the client instance itself. `MongoClient.connect()` will pass the client instance in the callback and you should use it to invoke `startSession()` on it.

Try this:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://someone:someone@somecluster.xxxyy.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

function dbConnect () {
    callback = callbackTrans;
    MongoClient.connect (uri, callback);
};

function callbackTrans (err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var session = client.startSession();
    console.log ('so far so good');
};

dbConnect();
```

References:

1. [connectCallback](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/MongoClient.html#.connect)
2. [startSession method](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/MongoClient.html#startSession)

Comment: Thanks very much. Silly me! :-(

Answer (score 1):

You have  to call the startSession method of the `db` parameter of the callback, this is what contains the method startSession if the connection is successful.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://someone:someone@somecluster.xxxyy.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

function dbConnect() {
    callback = callbackTrans;
    MongoClient.connect(uri, callback);
};

function callbackTrans(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var session = db.startSession();
    console.log ('so far so good');
};

dbConnect ();
```

Comment: Thanks too. Silly me! :-(